# Build on Heroku , Git issue with Push Failed, error in message :)

Tags: python, heroku

me again...can I please have some help, going a little bonkers here..

I have a simple Python script that I would like to connect to a scheduler task in Heroku...Its all going fine until I try deploy to Heroku. Its super simple script and its doing my mind in trying to work out why I cant deploy it.

Followed the instructions exactly from here..
https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/*********/deploy/heroku-git

Getting this error:

```
(base) simon@Simons-Air ********** % git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 47, done.
Counting objects: 100% (47/47), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (47/47), done.
Writing objects: 100% (47/47), 4.11 MiB | 581.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 47 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to **********.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/**********.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/**********.git'
```

Ive been into Heroku web interface and selected buildpack of Python (hoping that might be it), but still no luck.

Im on a Mac, using Visual Studio Code, with embedded terminal.

Any thoughts people?
Would be so grateful for any help.

Thanks again
Simon

Comment: "Ive been into Heroku web interface and selected buildpack of Python (hoping that might be it), but still no luck"—this error message does not match the action you say you've taken. You should receive a different error after doing this. Please make sure to ask a consistent question.

Comment: Assuming you are now getting something like "app not compatible with buildpack", this means you do not have a `requirements.txt`, `setup.py`, or `Pipfile` in the root (top) directory of your project. Does your project have any of those files?

Comment: Did you try reading https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks, like it suggests in the error message?

Comment: To be honest @Chris I dont, Im fairly new at both Python and Heroku so just finding my way.
I'll look into your suggestions...thankyou for your time, Im very grateful

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel I'll have a read of this...as I mentioned to Chris...fairly new, so thankyou for your patience. Appreciate you replying.